# Call contacts by typing their name in textbox

Tags: android, android-contacts

I wanted to know if there is any way to call a contact by simply typing his name(and clicking a `Button`). The application should directly call the contact and not ask any other confirmation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes there is. Look at this Library https://github.com/mwells/android.contact.picker.